# these three questions which are similar but not same. how?

Tags: c, logical-operators

Q1: Output ?

```
int main() { 
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m; 
    m = ++i && ++j || ++k; 
    printf ("%d %d %d %d", i,j,k,m); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Q2: Output ?

```
int main() { 
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m; 
    m = ++i || ++j && ++k; 
    printf ("%d %d %d %d", i,j,k,m); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Q3: Output ?

```
int main() { 
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m; 
    m = ++i && ++j && ++k; 
    printf ("%d %d %d %d", i,j,k,m); 
    return 0; 
}
```

please explain how this operation works?

Comment: But let us know what do you think.. and we'll discuss this together..

Comment: What's the difference in the source code ? Which assumption can you make based on it ?

Comment: [This Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) can explain you everything.

Comment: @Nobilis Wrong. Just because there is more than one `++` in an expression, it's not UB.

Comment: @H2CO3 I thought && and the like are not sequence points, are they?

Comment: @Nobilis Firstly, they are. Secondly, correct me if I'm wrong, but are the variables `i`, `j` and `k` the same? I suppose they aren't.

Comment: @Nobilis : && and || are sequence point : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azk8zbxd.aspx

Comment: @Nobilis if they weren't, only *the order of evaluation* was undefined.

Comment: @georgesl (but anyway, if theye weren't, that wouldn't be a problem either.)

Comment: @H2CO3 stupid oversight on my part, apologies for my statement and thanks for the clarification, will remove my comment.

Comment: I think you are looking for __short-circuit evaluation__. There are many related questions here on SO and this handy Wikipedia reference: [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: @Nobilis No problem, IIRC I've also got to know that from a comment on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean operations are handled from left to right (without brackets...). As soon as the result is fix it stops evaluating the rest of the condition. This means:

```
false && (AND) -> is always false, no matter what
true || (OR) -> is always true, no matter what

first case stops @ || (because true && true || doesn't matter)
second case stops @ || (because true || doesn't matter && how much && operations ...)
third case stops @ end (because true && true && -> still have to check because if there would be false, the whole expression would be false)
```

as it stops at the specific points the ++ operators aren't executed for the remaining stuff.

this is also the reason why you have to be careful to do stuff like incr, decr, or something in a condition...

Comment: +1 This should explain it well.